# RequestRefreshTokenAsync Sometimes Works Sometimes Errors

Tags: c#, identityserver4, access-token

I've inherited code and I'm trying to figure out why tokenResult sometimes has a valid access_token and sometimes returns an error "invalid_grant".  I am calling to refresh the token via:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(_identityUrl);
if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

var tokenResult = await client.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = "myclientid",
    RefreshToken = refreshToken
});
```

I checked, refreshToken has a value every time, success or error.

Comment: Are you using `OneTimeOnly` refresh tokens? If there is a network issue, the same refresh token could be sent more than once which fails from the second trial. If that is the case, you could implement a custom policy https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html

Comment: Quoted from https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html : The most common customization that you probably want to do is how to deal with refresh token replays. This is for situations where the token usage has been set to one-time only, but the same token gets sent more than once. This could either point to a replay attack of the refresh token, or to faulty client code like logic bugs or race conditions. The default implementation will reject the request, but here you can implement custom logic like grace periods, or revoking additional refresh or access tokens.

Comment: I have RefreshTokenUsage set to 0 which is ReUse.  Would it still reject it?  The scenario you are talking about makes sense why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  If I were to customize it, I assume I would need to change ValidateRefreshTokenAsync and just call base on default for the other two methods.  It says to call the base implementation first even on customized ones.